# flex write runtime errors stacktrace to file

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air, flex4

I am developing a Flex + AIR application. While debugging using Flash Builder sometimes I get runtime errors dialog with 'continue' & 'dismiss all' buttons. But when I release a build(.air) & run the application after installing. Then I don't get the same dialog in the release build.

I need to track these types of runtime errors for that I am trying to write them to a file as logs.

I tried using try catch & writing to file in catch block, but I am not able to get any wayout for unhandled exceptions or runtime errors.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error dialog is displayed only if you use the debugger version of Flash Player.

You could register an `UncaughtErrorEvent` handler and log the errors with `trace` or with the [logging API](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=logging_08.html):

```
private function onApplicationComplete():void
{
    loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(
        UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, onUncaughtError);
}

private function onUncaughtError(event:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
{
    trace(error);
}
```

Comment: Hi Splash,
I am not getting any "loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents" & also UncaughtErrorEvent is giving compile time error.

Comment: Flash Player 10.1 or AIR 2 is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can't debug compiled AIR application with the Flash debug player because the debug information is removed when you make a release build. You can use something like [De MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/) to output error information, but generally it's a bad idea to show error info in a release build. You should be testing prior to releasing.

Answer (score 0):

In Flash 11.5+ it is now possible to get the stack trace at runtime using error.getStackTrace() see http://renaun.com/blog/2012/09/getting-the-stack-trace-in-a-release-flash-player/

It is working for me in an Air application.